# Why does my search field drop down a line on screens smaller than 768px?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Working with an angular and bootstrap navbar. When the screen is resized horizontally below 768px the search field at the right falls down to the line below. I am trying to keep it in the top line and just let the navbar overflow to the right.

Here's a plunker! http://plnkr.co/edit/krAGXP6JEVZpLFNvRlsw?p=preview

I am using Chrome 32 to test this widget.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Umbrella_Corporation_logo.png" style="width: 31px;height:35px;"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Foo</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Bar</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Baz</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Bop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" />
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Why does this silly search field insist upon dropping down a line on smaller screens?

Comment: Looks like there's a min-width media query set on `.navbar-header` and  `.navbar-nav` for their floats with a minimum width of 768px, if it falls below that it loses it's float and knocks the form down, which inherits a full block width.

Comment: And possibly the `navbar-nav`'s `<li>`

Comment: I've tried commenting out all media queries at the 768px boundary and have not seen any change in the behaviour of this search box. My typical approach to this sort of problem is to pop the element inspector and toggle the browser width back and forth across the boundary while looking for changes to the CSS on affected elements and their surroundings but in this case I have examined every tag on the page and I'm not seeing any changes. Can you provide any more specific information regarding the media query that you referred to in your original comment?

Comment: Sure - added some stuff below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evan and mccannf helped me to identify that my width styles were being updated but their values weren't being accurately reflected within the chrome dev tools. Building from their recommendations I found that the following addition to my css was the best solution.

```
.pull-right .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Corrected: The *input-group-btn* seemed to be the cause of the problems for me.

Adding this:

```
.navbar-form .input-group-btn {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-form .input-group {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Ensured the search never jumped down.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vawHmODWL2N9P0CzD3JY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a combination of a few items. First being the `min-width` width media query for a few items floating only when the screen size is above 767px. ( you could put these inside a `max-width` instead of leave them default, however you want to set it up )

```
.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
}
```

And then this little bugger's width within a `min-width` query throwing a wrench into the flow set on another media query

```
.input-group-btn {
    width: 1%;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Again, I set a few items without the query, which you could stuff into a `max-width` query or just have them default.

http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/9xtLtrr4/